# SDL2 TTF "Freeing memory" but not actually "Freeing memory"

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am trying to edit text in SDL2 TTF, and I noticed as i was adding/subtracting text, the memory was not going down. The problem may possibly be in the `SDL_DestroyTexture` and `SDL_FreeSurface` but its also posing an issue with loading fonts. The way I have text is after the first instance of text, I load the fonts required. Then when the last instance is "free'd" i close the fonts. Here is the code for it (`Individual_Characters` is my class for text, basically an array of them)

**Loading the texture**

```
void Individual_Characters::Load_Character_Texture(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    if (characterTexture != NULL){
        SDL_DestroyTexture(characterTexture);
        characterTexture = NULL;
    }



    if (character != "")
    {


        SDL_Surface *characterSurface = NULL;


        if (bold == true){
            characterSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(fontsBold[fontIndex], character.c_str(), characterColour);
        }

        if (bold == false){
            characterSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(fonts[fontIndex], character.c_str(), characterColour);
        }



        if (!characterSurface){
            std::cout << "Could not create surface " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        }

        else{
            characterTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, characterSurface);
            SDL_FreeSurface(characterSurface);
            characterSurface = NULL;
        }


        SDL_QueryTexture(characterTexture, NULL, NULL, &characterRect.w, &characterRect.h);


    }

    else {

        characterRect.w = 0;
        characterRect.h = 0;

    }




}
```

**Setting up the individual character**

```
void Individual_Characters::Setup(SDL_Renderer *renderer, std::string p_character, int p_x, int p_y, int p_characterSize, SDL_Colour p_colour, bool p_bold, bool p_clickable, std::string p_fontType)
{
    if (setup == false){


        characterRect.x = p_x;
        characterRect.y = p_y;

        character = p_character;
        characterFont = p_fontType;
        characterSize = p_characterSize;
        characterColour = p_colour;
        clickable = p_clickable;
        bold = p_bold;


        fontIndex = characterSize - lowestFontSize -1;


        numOfInstances += 1;

        if (numOfInstances == 1){

            std::cout << "Character instance where initialising fonts  " << character << std::endl;

            TTF_Init();

            fonts.reserve(highestFontSize-lowestFontSize+1);
            fontsBold.reserve(highestFontSize-lowestFontSize+1);

            for (int i=lowestFontSize; i <= highestFontSize; i++)
            {
                TTF_Font *currentFont = TTF_OpenFont(characterFont.c_str(), i);

                TTF_Font *currentFontBold = TTF_OpenFont(characterFont.c_str(), i);
                TTF_SetFontStyle(currentFontBold, TTF_STYLE_BOLD);

                fonts.push_back(currentFont);
                fontsBold.push_back(currentFontBold);

            }

        }



        Load_Character_Texture(renderer);



    }



    setup = true;

}
```

and Then when i "backspace" I call this **first** and pop_back my vector after of `Individual_Characters` after.

```
void Individual_Characters::Free_All()
{

    if (setup == true){



        if (characterTexture != NULL){
            SDL_DestroyTexture(characterTexture);
        }



        if (numOfInstances == 1){

            std::cout << "Character instance where closing fonts  " << character << std::endl;

            for (int i=0; i < fonts.size(); i++){
                TTF_CloseFont(fonts[i]);
                TTF_CloseFont(fontsBold[i]);
            }

            fonts.clear();
            fontsBold.clear();

            TTF_Quit();

        }


        numOfInstances -= 1;


    }


    setup = false;


}
```

`numOfInstances` is how many instances of `Individual_Characters` I have, as I delete all the existing text, the output lets me know that the fonts were, in fact, closed. Regardless of this. Before text is loaded, the program sits at about `30mb` ram, as the fonts load, `70mb` ram. This is fine, but as the program uses the `TTF_CloseFont()`, the memory still remains at 70mb even AFTER it is freed.

Comment: The valid test is if you performed all of this in a loop that iterates a thousand times.  Does the memory increase in that case on each iteration?  If not, then what you're seeing is how the C++ memory manager works -- it does not naively return the memory back to the operating system -- instead it keeps the memory in case there are further allocations that will be done.

Comment: I test this by adding input and subtracting input. As I add input (first letter) i get the output saying , ```Character instance where initializing fonts "a" ``` for example and when i backspace it, I get ```Character instance where closing fonts "a" ```. The memory is not free'd by the OS, but aparently so by the program. This is an issue, though because when i ADD text, lets say a 1000 long string, it might use a few 100mb ram, then when i backspace it all, that memory is not freed to the OS, rather only in the program. Adding text does not use more until it reaches prior usage maximum

Comment: @peterwilson That's not a SDL related problem, but common.

Comment: If what I said is unclear, basically I type a bunch of stuff, program goes from 70mb - 500mb, then as i backspace it all, stays at 500. When I then add text, it does not go to 501mb until i reach the same text length effectively and then some

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ its the memory managment of SDL2, because as i Free_Surface and texture, it ```should``` use less memory

Comment: @peterwilson And what do you believe is SDL's memory management based on, if not the lower level native methods?

Comment: What I believe about it is its an issue that you can only cumulatively grow in memory in SDL2 ttf, by any means of my method, it would seem impossible to go from 500mb back to 70mb unless there is an issue in my code. What I would expect to happen is the program to only use the amount of memory I am requring not keep adjusting the maximum usage and then increase it as it gets higher, rather adapt to the current usage instead.

Comment: I could copy and paste a 10000 long string of text and then ```undo``` it and it would free it, but by whats happening the program will be a blank screen with blank text and be using over 1bg ram

Comment: *What I would expect to happen is the program to only use the amount of memory I am requring* -- The memory manager assumes you require 1GB, because that is what your program allocated.  If the memory manager did a one-to-one allocation / deallocation scheme with the underlying OS, expect your program to run a lot slower.  Also so far, you haven't proven that you are getting an "out of memory" condition -- the only thing is some sort of fear that the memory may run out.  That's why in the first comment, I asked if you ran your code in a loop.

Comment: What do you mean run this code in a loop? As in add text, subtract text all in the same loop? If thats what you mean then yes, the program does not use more and more memory, just doesn't go donw

Comment: This actually only occurs in linux. Windows deallocated/deassigns memory as I am not using it. It doesn't run *that much slower*

Comment: Linux nor Windows are C++ compilers.  It is the compiler's implementation of the heap manager that is responsible for this, not the operating system.  You could write your own heap manager that immediately gives back memory to the OS for every `delete` call, and that would work with any compiler.  The duplicate link of the closed question explains this rather well.

Comment: It is possible space is used by graphics driver for textures data. Probably easiest way to check is to run a loop that creates multiple character surfaces but not textures.